# How to deploy ziped lambda code from s3 using code deploy service alone?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-serverless

I'm trying to deploy the zipped lambda functions to lambda application using codedeploy but unable to deploy. But i'm able to switch traffic from alreday existing lambda current version to newer versions..using appspec file declaration. Not sure if codedeploy support deployment of lambdas. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy supports deployment to Lambda natively.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/applications-create-lambda.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-lambda-sam.html

Comment: Thanks Shariqmaws. So no need to mention

Comment: Thanks Shariqmaw, so no need to mention appspec file ?? Also, i tried zipping the lambda code and sam template into s3 bucket..but when i'm create deployment in codedeploy its not showing allowing me to select zip option. I can only select .yaml or .json in revion file type

Comment: You will need an appspec file for CodeDeploy, See an Example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-lambda

Comment: Ok, so i need to zip up appspec, lambda application code and SAM resource creation templates into s3 bucket and use codedeploy to trigger ? But i dont see any option to get source code in  code deploy from console, the only revion type allowed for lambda deployments are only .yaml and .jason. zip format revison filetype is not showi for lambda deployment in code deploy..