# How to upload zip file from S3 to Lambda using CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Since i'm not able to comment to the question: [How to deploy ziped lambda code from s3 using code deploy service alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114761/how-to-deploy-ziped-lambda-code-from-s3-using-code-deploy-service-alone) i need to ask it again. I'm using AWS CodeBuild to use my Code from CodeCommit for creating Artifacts. I'd like to use those Artifacts as Input for my lambda functions. I'M NOT USING SAM.

I have an appspec.yml in my repo and can build it as second artifact on my bucket so deploy is able to find and "deploy" it but the main problem remains: the code doesn't get updated to the contents of the zip file. Regardless of I'm using a zip or a dir and regardless of I'm placing the appspec in my unzipped artifact or next to my zipped artifact. I've found this video: https://youtu.be/mYcRPKeCPXc. But I just don't get how his code is being updated without mentioning his zip file anywhere.